# prevent rerendering of some component inside array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering

Suppose, i have a component `Parent` and i am rendering children like this.

```js
const [items,setItems] = useState([1,2,3,4,5,6....]);
const [pointer,setPointer] = useState(0);
// inside return
{items.map((item,idx)=>{
    return <ChildCanvas text={item} isPointer={pointer===idx} key={idx} idx={idx}/>
})}
```

`pointer` and `items` both are **different** states in the same component. Whenever `pointer` changes I am doing some animation inside that child`(pointer===idx)`.

At a time, `isPointer` will be true for only one **ChildCanvas** component. Here I am expecting that, react will rerender the child whose `isPointer` props has been changed.

But, here whenever `isPointer` changes, React is rerendering all `ChildCanvas` components. `ChildCanvas` is a heavy component, so this makes the page `(unresponsive for some time)`.

> How i checked if a particular `ChildCanvas` has been rerendered or not.

```js
function ChildCanvas({text,isPointer,idx}){
    console.log(`child ${idx} has been rerendered`);
    return // code...
}
```

Now, whenever `pointer` changes then i am getting this

```js
child 0 has been rerendered
child 1 has been rerendered
child 1 has been rerendered
// up to the length of the array
```

How can i make sure to rerender only the component whose `isPointer` props has been changed.

Comment: function components do not have a `shouldComponentUpdate` like class components. The idea behind function components is that you use things like `useState`, `useMemo` and `useCallback` to only run heavy calculations when they need to run and the rest should be insignificant to performance (for the most part). There is another option which is to use `memo` (`React.memo`) which essentially provides a `shouldComponentUpdate` to function components. I would look at correcting this issue with hooks over defaulting to `memo`.

Comment: Okay, I'll see.